# Add-Content from powershell loop to CSV file with different columns

Tags: powershell, csv

I currently have a script that will loop through a group of files in a folder - open each one up and let me enter a new file name and then rename it. I am then trying to create a CSV file with the old name in one column and the new name of the file in the second column.

```powershell
#[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic 

$folderpath = 'C:\Scans\docs\' '#
$items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folderpath *.pdf
$newFileName = "" 
$counterID = 0
$amountOfScans = $items.Length

foreach( $i in $items)  {
    Start-Process ((Resolve-Path ("$folderpath$i")).Path)

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    $counterID++ 

    $newFileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the new file name $counterID / $amountOfScans :", $i) 

    Stop-Process -Name "Acro*"

    Add-Content -Path 'C:\Scans\fileNames.csv' -Value "$i","$newFileName "

    Rename-Item $i.FullName ("$newName.pdf")
}
```

This does work but it outputs into the csv only in the first column like:

```
old file name 1
new file name 1
old file name 2
new file name 2
```

How do make this output:

```
old file name 1 | new file name 1
old file name 2 | new file name 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an array.  A CSV is nothing more than a text file, so you want to pass the entire line as a single string.

```
Add-Content -Path 'C:\Scans\fileNames.csv' -Value "`"$i`",`"$newFileName`""
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this as the answer if it solved your question.